# calculate area of colored content of a image

Tags: image

I have a picture and I want to know how much it will cost me to print that image. For this I need to calculate the area that will be printed (excluding transparent areas or white color), is any tools (or html+php or jquery maybe) to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use gd library to load the image and inspect it.
I would read each pixel in the image and assign a cost to it by summing up the complement of RGB values. In pseudo code

```
cost = 0
im = gd_load_image("myimage.png");
for(row in im->width) {
    for(col in im->height) {
        pixel = im->getPixel(row, col);
        r = 255 - pixel->r
        g = 255 - pixel->g
        b = 255 - pixel->b
        cost += (r+g+b);
    }
}
echo "It wil cost you: $cost"
```

This is just an idea, but the cost value could be reasonably trusted